# Basic emacs keybindings in emacs.stackexchange.com?

Tags: feature-request

It would be cool to have some basic emacs keybindings in emacs.stackexchange.com!

Answer (score 3):

Stack Exchange doesn't do custom keybindings per site.

You can use the keyboard to interact with the site. Press `?` to see the available shortcuts. The shortcuts are not particularly emacsy, but then most commands to interact with the site aren't standard commands that have an Emacs keybinding. You need to enable keyboard shortcuts in your [profile](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/preferences) first. Annoyingly, you need to do that for every site, or to install a deprecated [browser extension](https://stackapps.com/questions/2567/official-keyboard-shortcuts) to enable the keyboard shortcuts everywhere.

There are browser extensions that apply to any site to improve the experience for Emacs users:

- Emacs keybindings: [Emacsome (Chrome)](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/emacsome/lacfhpppojhdlhojhcmcpbbijpcpjfja), do it yourself with [Shortkeys (Chrome)](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/shortkeys-custom-keyboard/logpjaacgmcbpdkdchjiaagddngobkck), [emacs-shortcuts (Firefox)](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/emacs-shortcuts/).
- [Call Emacs to edit the content of text boxes](http://wikemacs.org/wiki/Emacs_as_a_web_browser%27s_external_editor): [Edit with Emacs (Chrome, Safari)](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/edit-with-emacs/ljobjlafonikaiipfkggjbhkghgicgoh), [Emacs (Chrome)](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/emacs/pledjnbikkbieemanocnjeoacdcphlgf), [Firemacs (Firefox)](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firemacs/). Or use [Conkeror](http://www.conkeror.org/) instead of Firefox.

But if you really want an Emacs-like experience… **access the site in Emacs with [`sx.el` — Stack Exchange for Emacs](https://stackapps.com/questions/3950/sx-stack-exchange-for-emacs)**! This is an Emacs package (available from MELPA) by [Sean Allred](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/2264/sean-allred), [Malabarba](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/50/malabarba) and others. It doesn't support all the site's features, and development has stalled, but you can use it to browse, ask, answer, edit and comment.

Comment: Wow I did not know sx.el

Comment: sx.el is really great!